# Qt creator - RS232 writing over serial to fast

Tags: c++, serial-port, qt-creator, robotics

```
for(int i = 0; i < receivedACLCommands.count(); i++ )
{
    QByteArray s = receivedACLCommands[i].toLatin1();
    serialport->write(s);
    serialport->waitForBytesWritten(1000);
}
```

In my method I have a QStringList that contains all my commands. The commands will be send to a PID controller that needs to process the command before a new one I being send. I tried this with the `waitForBytesWriten` but this isnt working for me.

*the controller is an old SCORBOT controller-a.(works with ACL commands).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, waitForBytesWritten() isn't going to solve that.  Only other thing you can do is sleep for a while after the wait call, thus giving the device some time to process the command you have just written.  Exactly how long to sleep is of course a blind guess, it is not necessarily a constant.

Do focus on enabling handshaking first, typically ignored too often.  QSerialPort::setFlowControl() function.  A decent device will use its RTS signal to turn off your CTS input (Clear to Send) when it isn't ready to receive anything.  CTS/RTS handshaking is supported by Qt, you use QSerialPort::HardwareControl

Comment: thankyou, so in my **for** loop I should wait for the `ClearToSendSignal` to turn true again, do I need to make a request to write? Or is the signal automatically being set to true again by the handshaking protocol?

Comment: Don't help beyond setFlowControl(), the driver already knows how to take care of CTS/RTS handshaking.  Assuming the device actually uses it, you can ask *somebody* to be sure.  If you have not tried this at all yet then very decent odds that it solves your problem.

Comment: tried to find if the device uses CTS/RTS handshaking by reading documentation, nothing was written about it. So I tried the following, I called `QSerialPort::pinoutSignals()` this method return the following: `QFlags (0x4|0x10|0x40|0x80)` The last two hex number are the signals for CTS/RTS, does this assure the presence of the handshake? First time working with RS232, sorry for asking so much.

Comment: You can only be sure when you observe CTS turned off for a brief amount of time.  That's easy to miss.  Beyond using a telephone, the best way to tell is that you simply don't have a problem anymore.